# how could i decrease residual voltage of 11KV bus that Is created by direct online 9MVA induction Emotor?

Tags: power-grid

We have power grid 11KV (bus A & bus B) with 2 incoming and one coupling breaker between them;bus A have a outgoing that feed 9MVA induction Emotor;
incoming A and B and coupling Equipped with ATS system;
after cut off incoming A voltage ATS system opens up incoming A and close coupling and bus A now fed by incoming B;
after close coupling breaker because of existence residual voltage in the bus A that comes from 9MVA induction Emotor ; 9MVA induction Emotor trip by i differential that Arises of coupling voltage of bus B and residual voltage of bus A 
question is:
1.how could i decrease mentioned residual voltage?
2.Is there protection relay that in the proper time provide permit to close the coupling breaker to prevent of create i differential in the mentioned Emotor? (except of 27R because we have it and it is not proper function for this reason)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the induction motor is acting as a generator, and is taking some time to stop.

You have a few choices here, you can (if it is acceptable) open the motor breaker before the ATS switches over, cut over to the other bus and then do whatever a normal motor startup looks like once the load has stopped spinning (Brake resistors may help here).

If the two busses are phase synchronous then you could try to make the ATS transfer happen quickly enough that the slip has not become excessive, some sums will be needed to see both how much slip you can accommodate and how long it takes that motor to slip that much once the bus drops off line, the mechanical time constants will matter here.

You could cut some starting resistance into circuit to limit the current while everything pulls back into sync.

Lots of ways to skin this, it just depends on what that motor is driving, and can you accept a wait and restart on the motor.